# How to define a lot of symbols in SymPy

Tags: sympy, repeat, symbols

I am trying to define a lot of variables in "sympy" for symbolic processing.

```py
import sympy as sp

b_0 = sp.symbols('b_0')
b_1 = sp.symbols('b_1')
...
b_X = sp.symbols('b_X')
```

and so on with the `X` going from 1 to 1000.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

There are a few options:

```
>>> sp.symbols('b_0:10')
(b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, b_7, b_8, b_9)
```

or, using a formatted string,

```
>>> n = 10
>>> sp.symbols('b_0:{}'.format(n))
(b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, b_7, b_8, b_9)
```

These return a tuple of symbols. There are more formatting options: see [`symbols` docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#symbols).

There is also a function to generate a NumPy array of symbols:

```
>>> sp.symarray('b', 10)
array([b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, b_7, b_8, b_9], dtype=object)
```

All of these examples are meant to be assigned to something. For example, `b = sp.symbols('b_0:10')` assigns the tuple of symbols to b, so they can be accessed as `b[0], b[1]`, etc.   SymPy symbols are **not** accessed by the string representing them, such as `"b_0" or "b_1"`.

---

Finally, there are [Indexed objects](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/indexed.html) in case you need an array of symbols of undetermined size: Indexed objects are created on the fly as you use `A[n]` notation with `A` being an IndexedBase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! `sp.symarray('A',10)
B=sp.diff(A,A_1)` when i try this it says the A_1 is undefined. the other methods also say A_1 is undefined. I am looking for a way to get the python 2.7 to acknowledge the created variables.

Comment: These are supposed to be assigned to something. I edited the answer. Take note of the difference between Python variable name and SymPy symbol name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to still be able to call individuals symbols, like `b_0`:

Since:

```py
from sympy import symbols

# Number of symbols you need
X = 5

b = symbols(f"b_0:{X}")
>>> b
(b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)

>>> b_0
NameError: name 'b_0' is not defined
```

You could add them to the local variables through a dictionary:

```py
from sympy import symbols

# Number of symbols you need
X = 5

# To still have b[i]
b = symbols(f"b_0:{X}")

b_dict = {f"b_{i}": b[i] for i in range(X)}
locals().update(b_dict)
```

Comment: Since this exercise is about DRY, b_dict can be created without repeating the schema: `b_dict = {str(symbol):symbol for symbol in b}`

Comment: Hmm, [sympy.var()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.var) seems to be a perfect solution to the question, except that it apparently injects the variables into globals() instead of locals(), making it useless if we want modular code.  How annoying.