# shortcut for defining symbols in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I often have a set of symbols I'd like to define at the beginning of a chunk of `sympy` code. The 'boneheaded' approach is

```py
from sympy import symbols
alpha, beta, delta, gamma = symbols("alpha,beta,delta,gamma")
```

but this feels terribly wasteful/redundant. I think the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226812/how-to-define-a-lot-of-symbols-in-sympy) get me most of the way there; ideally I'd like a function where I could say

```py
foo(("alpha", "beta", "delta", "gamma"))
```

(or possibly `foo("alpha", "beta", "delta", "gamma")`, whichever seems to be more Pythonic) and have these symbols added to my environment.

Comment: What about [`var()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#var)  ? See also [Difference between var and Symbol in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897901/difference-between-var-and-symbol-in-sympy)

Comment: As explained in the link, `sympy.var` does what you want.  But look at its code - it does `symbols`, followed by 'injecting' the Python variables into the `globals`.  So there's nothing wasteful about your use of `symbols` - unless you are paying for keystrokes :)  Generally we discourage creating python variables dynamically.  Code is more readable, and debuggable if all variable assignments are explicit.

Comment: I take the general point about best practices (in the [r] tag we're constantly telling people not to dynamically generate variables but to use lists etc. instead). However, since I usually use `sympy` in very interactive mode, I think I like this version ... (dumb/newbie question: how do I view the code of `sympy.var` ?  Do I need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562759/can-python-print-a-function-definition ?

Comment: @JohanC, if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it ...

Comment: You may just use `isympy -I` with ipython / jupyter installed...

Answer (score 0):

I think this (a slight modification of the examples given in the linked question) will do it:

```py
def makesyms(s):
   globals().update(dict(zip(s, symbols(s))))
   return None

makesyms(("a", "b", "c"))
```

or

```py
def makesyms2(*s):
   globals().update(dict(zip(s, symbols(s))))
   return None

makesyms2("A", "B", "C")
```